# Bytescout.SpreadSheet do not read first line (winform application)

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, visual-studio-2013

I am using bytescout.spreadsheet (nuGet package) to read csv in windows form application (using C#).
There are some simple steps given to read csv

```
Spreadsheet document = new Spreadsheet();
document.LoadFromFile(@"E:\Stock Exchange\Moosani.com\May 2014\06052014.csv");
DataSet ds = document.ExportToDataSet();
```

This code works fine but when I check the data set ds, it starts from second record. It is probably considering first row as column headers but there is no such configuration I found on "document" object. My csv file do not have column headers and I don't want to insert it.
Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Use LoadFromStream instead of LoadFromFile.

Write a custom Stream class that returns the bytes that make up the header line, and then pass through calls to read your text file afterwards.